# Android thread id check

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Google's gtalksms for Android uses a Handler inside a Service.  When it starts the handler thread it stores the thread id and then in the Handler has the following check:

```
if (Thread.currentThread().getId() != mHandlerThreadId) {
        throw new IllegalThreadStateException();
}
```

My question is why would you need this type of check?  Is it good practice or something?  I am very new to multithreading.

**EDIT:**

Just to be clear, this is the HandlerThread:

```
    HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("My.Service");
    handlerThread.start();
    mHandlerThreadId = handlerThread.getId();
    ServiceHandler serviceHandler = new ServiceHandler(handlerThread.getLooper());
```

Comment: this will check if the current thread is the same as UI thread .

Comment: I don't think so, this is the thread id of the Handler thread.

Comment: the handler doesn't have its own thread, it runs on UI thread

Comment: I've edited my question, doesn't the above show that the Handler is on it's own thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why would you need this type of check?

The statement makes sure that the method is being run on the HandlerThread. Typically, if an object or a process needs to be single threaded, this is one way to check that the object is used properly. If somebody calls it from several thread there will be an exception.

One usual example is GUIs which are almost always meant to be single threaded - some implementations do these types of checks to make sure you always change UI components from the UI Thread.

In this specific case, I don't know the details of that library but I suppose that it does not behave as expected in a multi-threaded environment and the developer introduced that check to forbid such a usage.

Note: techncially, it is unlikely that two threads have the same ID but not impossible, so the check could also be: `if (Thread.currentThread().equals(handlerThread));`